# MariaDB Connector J : autoReconnect does not wok for Basic Faillover

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, driver, mysql-connector

From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/, for option autoReconnect, When this parameter enabled when a Failover and Load Balancing Mode is not in use, the connector will simply try to reconnect to its host after a failure. This is referred to as Basic Failover.

But the problem is that the reconnect does not work after server failure. The test code is as follows:

```
@Test
public void waitTimeoutResultSetTest() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {

    try (Connection connection = setBlankConnection("&autoReconnect=true")) {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
    assertTrue(rs.next());

    stmt.execute("set session wait_timeout=1");

    Thread.sleep(3000); // Wait for the server to kill the connection

    try {
       rs = stmt.executeQuery("show databases;");
       assertTrue(rs.next());

       System.out.println("position 1");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      //normal exception
      System.out.println("position 2");
    }
    }
}
```

With autoReconnect, I think the expected result is that it will get to position 1, but actually it will get to position 2, with exception that "Connection reset by peer: socket write error."

My question is that whether the basic failover does not work, or my test code is wrong? I cannot find other information from web, could you kindly give me some explanation if you know about it?